# Latex report displays page number is different places

Tags: chapters, page-numbering

I am quite new to Latex and trying to make the report based on the template provided by my professor.

I am observing that latex is displaying the page number in different places such as for some page it displays the page number in the `top-right` corner and for some page, it displays in `bottom-centre`. Is this expected? Also, when the page number is displayed on the top-right corner then the chapter names appear on the top-left corner.

1. Is it possible for me to have the page number only on bottom-centre for all pages?
2. Also, why only on some pages the chapter heading is displayed on the top-left corner? Is this something to do with `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}` I am using?
3. Is it possible for me to have the roman numbers for contents, abstract, list of table and images? I know if I use `book` I can achieve this but if I use book then my images and text is getting messed up so I am using the report. Is there any possibility to achieve the same using the `{report}`.

The page number on bottom-centre and top-right:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwJ1H.png

Following are the template which are provided by my professor:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage[english]{selnolig}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[usegeometry,
            margin=20mm,
            twoside=semi]

\usepackage{acronym}
    \renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{{\rmfamily #1}} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{icomma} 
\usepackage{ltablex}   
\usepackage{newfile}   
\usepackage{overpic}   
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{url}

\parindent 2em         
\parskip 0.5em          

\pagestyle{headings}

%THIS IS WHERE SOME COMMON conctent added


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\usepackage{makeidx}         
\makeindex                    

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}    
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}       


\author{\dcauthorfirstname~\dcauthorlastname}
\title{\dctitle}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter


\section*{\centering Acknowledgements}
%THIS IS WHERE I ADD THE Acknowledgements FROM ANOTHER FILE

\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}
%-----------------------------
% Abstract
%-----------------------------
\section*{\centering Abstract}
%THIS IS WHERE I ADD THE ABSTRACT FROM ANOTHER FILE

\vfill
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

\pagestyle{headings}


\tableofcontents            \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\listoffigures              \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\listoftables               \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

%THIS IS WHERE I ADD THE ACCRONYMS FROM ANOTHER FILE
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}    
\mainmatter 
\acresetall

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter{Introduction}
%THis is where I include the Introduction text from another file

\chapter{Conclusion}
%THis is where I include the Conclusion text from another file


\begin{appendix}

\chapter{Appendix}
\label{chap:Appendix}
%THis is where I include the Appendix text from another file

\end{appendix}

\backmatter

\printindex


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: we can not run your example code as it uses files not available, but avoid putting formatting into section headings like `\chapter{\centering Introduction}` as this will make `\centering` part of the text and will get used everywhere the text is used including page running heads and table of contents. Do you really use _all_ those packages in this document? It seems a massively over-complicated preamble.

Comment: It is quite normal (and the default design in report) for chapter opening pages to have a different page style with no page head and the page number at the bottom. (`\thispagestyle{plain}`)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, the `\centering` is something I was trying but its not there in the final code. I have removed the same from the above question. Actually, most of the packages come from the department provided template and I am quite new to latex so I am not entirely sure if the document is using all or not

Comment: such templates make debugging anything harder as there are so many possibilities for conflict.  If you just start from `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report} \begin{document}` and only add packages that you need it is much easier to control.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I completely understand but since I have received the template I just continued using the same and did not want to remove any packages as it may impact the remaining code. I have removed a couple of things which I am sure is not required in this question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you please have a look at it now and provide some suggestions? Because I am not sure if this issue is quite normal as I did not find any relevant questions on the same topic.

Comment: Please edit the code by commenting all of the `input{...}` as these files are not available to us.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 I tried as you requested but it returns the error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown option \`margin=20mm' for package \`typearea'.`

Comment: your last question, 3,  isn't really answerable, what does "messed up " mean, if you get a tex error then show the exact error from the log file. There are almost no differences between book and report they are generated from the same file, just different defaults and three or four extra commands to structure front matter in book.

Comment: @Tanvir I have edited the code and removed the `input`. If possible have a look and please provide your suggestions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Regarding Question 3, I would like to have roman number (i,ii,iii) as page number to my report until the start of `Chapter 1 Introduction` part and then after I would like to has normal numbers (1,2,3) for all the chapters. Similar to how we see in the books. I am not getting any error as everything is working fine. `Messed up` means when I add images with `Float [H]` then it adds some space between previous and subsequent text/section due to which report looks a bit messed up.

Comment: `[H]`  disables the mechanism that latex uses to avoid bad white space at a page breaks (floating figures) so _by design_ introduces ugly white space unless you manually position the figure at a good place in the source to get a good page break. It is opting for manual control and should only be used in exceptional cases. `\pagenumbering{roman}`  then later `\pagenumbering{arabic}` will do your page numbers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the response I added `\pagenumbering{roman}` before my title page and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` before my Introduction. That fixed the issue. Regarding the page number displayed in different places I fixed it by adding the command `\pagestyle{plain}`.  If you want add these commands as answer to this question. I will accept it and we can close this questions. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In report class you can get a centred page number in the page foot, and no page head using

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

(Which is the style already used on chapter openings)

You can use

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
```

and

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

To use roman or arabic numbers, setting the page count to 1 in each case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. That worked !!!!